# I can't get my class to work in pygame

Tags: python, class, pygame

```
import pygame, sys, time, os, copy

from pygame.locals import *


forest = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/forest.png')

rstill = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/rstill.bmp')
lstill = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/lstill.bmp')
bstill = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/bstill.bmp')
fstill = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/fstill.bmp')

lwalk1 = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/lwalk1.bmp')
lwalk2 = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/lwalk2.bmp')
rwalk1 = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/rwalk1.bmp')
rwalk2 = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/rwalk2.bmp')
fwalk1 = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/fwalk1.bmp')
fwalk2 = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/fwalk2.bmp')
bwalk1 = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/bwalk1.bmp')
bwalk2 = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/bwalk2.bmp')


class character():
    def __init__(self, walk1, still, walk2):
        self.sprite = sprite
        self.walk1 = walk1
        self.still = still
        self.walk2 = walk2

    def move(self, walk1, still, walk2, sprite):
        timer = clock.tick()
        if timer > 9:

            if sprite == walk1: 
                self.sprite = still

            elif sprite == still:
                self.sprite = walk2

            elif sprite == walk2:
                self.sprite = walk1

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((492,360))

background = forest
sprite = bstill
spritex = 240
spritey = 300
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
walk1 = fwalk1
walk2 = fwalk2
still = fstill


Character = character(walk1,still,walk2)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key == K_LEFT):
                spritex-=1
                walk1 = copy.deepcopy(lwalk1)
                walk2 = copy.deepcopy(lwalk2)
                still = copy.deepcopy(lstill)

            elif (event.key == K_RIGHT):
                spritex+=1
                walk1 = copy.deepcopy(rwalk1)
                walk2 = copy.deepcopy(rwalk2)
                still = copy.deepcopy(rstill)

            elif (event.key == K_UP):
                spritey-=1
                walk1 = copy.deepcopy(fwalk1)
                walk2 = copy.deepcopy(fwalk2)
                still = copy.deepcopy(fstill)

            elif (event.key == K_DOWN):
                spritey+=1
                walk1 = copy.deepcopy(bwalk1)
                walk2 = copy.deepcopy(bwalk2)
                still = copy.deepcopy(bstill)


    Character.move(walk1, still, walk2, sprite)

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(Character.sprite, (spritex, spritey)) 

    pygame.display.update()
```

My program never runs any of the three if statements inside character.move (it does run the timer one). I am new to pygame and classes, does anyone know if I've missed out anything big? The sprite will move with the arrow keys, but never changes image.
Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `timer = clock.tick()` for each time you call `walk()`? Will it ever be larger than 9? Also if you add a `print(type(sprite))` and `print(type(walk1))` or even `print(sprite == walk1)`, will they ever be True?

Comment: The value of timer = clock.tick() is over 9, but when printing, no, they are never true. I am trying to change something to do with the timer as I am not incrementing it?

Comment: Check your indentation, if event.type == KEYDOWN isn't in the for loop

Comment: also, welcome to SO!

Comment: I fixed the timer - it was simply making the value 0 again each iteration. Also, i was using copy.deepcopy which it didnt like! so i changed the pictures to a list and made the program index through the list to change pictures and it worked :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've yet to isolate your issue other than the fact that your comparison vs the active sprite and a image object doesn't add up to `True`.

But I wanted to give you a few pointers which are way to long for a comment and needs structure and code highlighting - so here's some general tips when doing graphics and classes.

### Images are resources, not sprites and should never be changed.

For instance, a image should usually only be loaded once.
Once loaded, it should sit there and normally you don't pass that around as an argument to be checked against *(either because it would be a lot of data to compare, or it might give you skewed results depending on the object being compared).*

Consider the following modification:

```
class character():
    def __init__(self, direction):
        self.rstill = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/rstill.bmp')
        self.lstill = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/lstill.bmp')
        self.bstill = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/bstill.bmp')
        self.fstill = pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/fstill.bmp')

        self.direction = direction
        if self.direction == 'up':
            self.sprite = self.fstill
        elif ...
        else ...

    def move(self, direction):
        if clock.tick() > 9: # No point in variable this unless you need to use it again.
            if direction == self.direction:
                self.sprite = self.fstill2
            elif direction == 'down':
                self.sprite = self.dstill
            else ...
```

Load the image resources in the class that needs them, and keep smaller pointers to for instance what direction they are moving.

It will be easier to debug and make comparisons easier for you and some times even for Python.

Not sure what you wanted to do with:

```
walk1 = copy.deepcopy(lwalk1)
walk2 = copy.deepcopy(lwalk2)
...
```

I think this is a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you think you have a solution - it didn't quite work - so now you're asking a question based on that solution.

I'm guessing you thought you'd copy an exact copy of the sprite and that would make it so you could compare them?

If that's the case, scrap that Idea because that's not where you problem lies.
Instead, keep static images in your sprite/character, load the resource you need to show right now into `self.sprite` but compare against `self.direction`.

### Handling animations

I'll also add in a small change on how you load each frame, because I'm guessing that's what `fwalk1` and `fwalk2` for instance are, two frames that should simulate an animation?

You could do this, and convert it into something "useful" by placing them in a list and loop over it and create a manual animation sequence based on several image resources.

```
self.lwalk = [ret_bitmap('lwalk1.bmp'), ret_bitmap('lwalk2.bmp')]
self.rwalk = [ret_bitmap('rwalk1.bmp'), ret_bitmap('rwalk2.bmp')]

self.animation_frame = 0
```

And ideally you would want to separate movement, updating what the user sees and changing the image. These are three different tasks even tho they are usually combined at the same time.

```
def move(x, y):
    # Should be in charge of moving the character and changing sprite

def update(direction):
    # Should be in charge of animation updates etc.

def get_image():
    # should return the current active frame/image (since you're working with animations)
```

If you combine it all, and tweak the things we've modified and gone through here.
Your class and code should look something like this:

```
import pygame, sys, time, os, copy
from pygame.locals import *

def ret_bitmap(fname):
    return pygame.image.load('C:/Python32/PygameImages/' + rstill.bmp)

class character():
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, direction='up'):

        self.rstill = [ret_bitmap('rstill.bmp')]
        self.lstill = [ret_bitmap('lstill.bmp')]
        self.bstill = [ret_bitmap('bstill.bmp')]
        self.fstill = [ret_bitmap('fstill.bmp')]

        self.lwalk = [ret_bitmap('lwalk1.bmp'), ret_bitmap('lwalk2.bmp')]
        self.rwalk = [ret_bitmap('rwalk1.bmp'), ret_bitmap('rwalk2.bmp')]
        self.fwalk = [ret_bitmap('fwalk1.bmp'), ret_bitmap('fwalk2.bmp')]
        self.bwalk = [ret_bitmap('bwalk1.bmp'), ret_bitmap('bwalk2.bmp')]

        self.direction = direction
        self.animation_frame = 0
        self.x, self.y = x, y

        ## == Load the first frame to show the user
        ##  Note: We don't load the image, we load the list.
        if self.direction == 'up':
            self.sprite = self.fwalk
        elif self.direction == 'down':
            self.sprite = self.bwalk
        elif self.direction == 'left':
            self.sprite = self.lwalk
        else:
            self.sprite = self.rwalk

    def move(self, direction):
        self.direction = direction

        if direction == 'left':
            self.x -= 1
            self.sprite = self.lwalk
        elif direction == 'right':
            self.x += 1
            self.sprite = self.rwalk
        elif direction == 'up':
            self.y += 1
            self.sprite = self.fwalk
        else: # Down
            self.y -= 1
            self.sprite = self.bwalk

    def update(self, direction):
        if clock.tick() > 9:
            self.animation_frame += 1

            if self.animation_frame > len(self.sprite):
                self.animation_frame = 0

    def get_image(self):
        return self.sprite[self.animation_frame]

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((492,360))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

Character = character(x=240, y=300, direction='down')
background = ret_bitmap('forest.png')

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if (event.key == K_LEFT):
            Character.move('left')

        elif (event.key == K_RIGHT):
            Character.move('right')

        elif (event.key == K_UP):
            Character.move('up')

        elif (event.key == K_DOWN):
            Character.move('down')

    Character.update() # Just updates the animation frame, if the time is right

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(Character.get_image(), (Character.x, Character.y)) 

    pygame.display.update()
```

Now keep in mind, I do not have Pygame installed.
I might have included your original problem which I think `DCA-` pointed out has to do with the timer.

I'm not totally sure how the timer works in Pygame since i use Pyglet myself where I usually keep track of the timing myself via `import time; time.time()`. Never the less, you could probably incorporate the correct answer to this code.

Or it works out of the box? Who knows : )

### Addition to animations

There's one way to use the same bitmap for the same animation sequence.
This is probably called something fancy, I call it "image animation regions".

[image]

Consider the following image.
You would simply assign a specific region per frame, and crop the image on every `def update()` call.

You could achieve this by using:

```
x = pygame.image.load(filename)
x.get_rect(x, y, width, height)
```

And essentially re-use the same image, just show the user a different region of that image. It's performance is usually a lot higher than having to change something in the graphical context (that is, changing the active image).

So for the future, consider implementing that when working with animations.

Best of luck in your project, I hope it works out! : )

Answer (score 0):

Your timer is being called and reset before it ever reaches 9

to solve this use:

```
def move(self, walk1, still, walk2, sprite):
    timer += clock.tick()
    if timer > 9:
        timer = 0
        if sprite == walk1: 
            self.sprite = still

        elif sprite == still:
            self.sprite = walk2

        elif sprite == walk2:
            self.sprite = walk1
```

This will add the amount of time every frame and when that total time is greater than 9 it will pass the if statement

you will also have to initialise the `timer`to 0 at the start of your program or in the `__init__` of the class e.g.

```
class character():
    def __init__(self, walk1, still, walk2):
        self.sprite = sprite
        self.walk1 = walk1
        self.still = still
        self.walk2 = walk2
        self.timer = 0

    def move(self, walk1, still, walk2, sprite):
        self.timer = clock.tick()
        if self.timer > 9:
            self.timer = 0
            if sprite == walk1: 
                self.sprite = still

            elif sprite == still:
                self.sprite = walk2

            elif sprite == walk2:
                self.sprite = walk1
```

Hope this helps